# how to give transition differently with delay in transform properties scale, transform,rotate etc

Tags: css

this is not right way to do i know that and it's not working anymore it's only done for understand my problem.

```
div
{
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0);
    transition:rotate 0.2s linear, translate 0.3s linear 0.2s;
}
div:hover
{
    transform: rotate(60deg) translate(40);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per css3 standards its not possible to achieve the same which you have mentioned. Instead you can make something like this.

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">
 </div>
</div>



.outer
{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  transform:translateX(0);
  transition:transform 2s linear;
}
.inner{
   width: inherit; height: inherit;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition:transform 2s linear;
   background:blue
}
.outer:hover
{
  transform: translateX(140px);  
}
.outer:hover .inner
{
   transform: rotate(160deg);

}
```

Comment: thanks bro for your comment..
but i want at hover event   rotate element and little delay translate that element with some value.....

Comment: @MishalRai Refer this updated https://jsfiddle.net/74yjcnz5/1/ .. For further enhancement just adjust the transition-delay property, Because im not sure what was your ask.

Comment: thank once again bro for your quick response 
but i think that not best way to solve that problem by adding extra div for single transform properties delay

plz check this link for more clear
http://codepen.io/raimishal123/pen/growYe?editors=0100 
i want just delay on transform properties currently it happened in same time.